# Is it possible to create a "LAN" game in Unity3D?

Tags: unity-game-engine, lan, multiplayer

I want to make a simple 2D card game. The game should be multiplayer and lan based. That is user can play the game on lan. Besides they should be able to commuinicate via headphone. So is there any help from unity side for this type of lan game making. If yes from where can i learn ?

Comment: Okay, go write it. Have fun!

Comment: @user2864740 you are a real helper

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unity3D has networking capabilities for multiplayer games. However I don't think that it supports teamspeak like communication but there are third party libraries for that I suppose. For learning resources it is right here http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/Manual/index.html